# How can I print a char array using while loop in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

```
public class Chararray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] c={1,2,3};
        while() // What should be the condition?
        {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I print a char array using while loop in Java?

Comment: You can use below link http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/12/3-example-to-print-array-values-in-java.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can can help solve [certain on-topic problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to **[put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** on the subject in the first place, including elementary **[(re)search](https://google.com/)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a local `int` variable that refers to the current index of the iteration and use it in the while condition :

```
char[] chars = {'1','2','3'}; 
int i = 0;
while(i < chars.length){
    System.out.println(chars[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Note that a `while` statement is not designed to iterate on all elements of an array.
Use rather a for or a foreach in this case :

```
char[] chars={'1','2','3'}; 

for (c : chars){
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

It makes a shorter code and it also avoids introducing a `int i` variable that will lives after the `for` statement.Which may create side effects it incorrectly reused.

Comment: You forgot to remove the `i++` in your second code and the characters need single quotes around them.

Comment: @TomerADev thanks :)

Comment: output is like "some code" i dont know what it is?    what to do?

Answer (score 0):

This approach won't work. If you want to iterate through all the characters of array use

```
for(char singleChar: c){
// Process your chars here one by one
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is your array itself. To prevent any errors, surround each number with quotes like `{'1','2','3'}`

Do you need to use a while loop? A for loop would work much easier:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] c = {'1','2','3'};
    for(int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(c[i]);
    }
}
```

And that will print all the values of the array, no matter how long it is.